# How does a scala object pass its type to a trait while extending the trait that requires a type parameter?

Tags: scala, typeerror

Let's say, I have the following trait.

```
trait Stringify[T] {
  def stringify(t:T):String;
}
```

The following works:

```
case class Simple() extends Stringify[Simple] {
  override def stringify(t: Simple): String = t.toString
}
```

However, the compiler throws an error (illegal cyclic reference) while I do something like this:

```
case object Simple2 extends Stringify[Simple2.type] {
  override def stringify(t: Simple2.type): String = "Simple2"
}
```

I can understand the error message. But, how do I achieve something like that in the case of an object ?

Comment: `case class Simple[Simple]() extends Stringify[Simple]`